# Creating default VPC using boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

Is there a way to do an equivalent of `aws ec2 create-default-vpc` using boto3? (more generally, I'm wondering if there is a way to figure out boto3/botocore equivalent of aws CLI directive)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`create_default_vpc()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.create_default_vpc):

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name = 'ap-southeast-2') # Adjust as desired

client.create_default_vpc()
```

It's all in the boto3 documentation! (In fact, the AWS CLI uses botocore!)

Comment: ah thanks, looks like I should get into habit of changing - to _ and just searching the API